# Send FileStream through Socket on C#

Tags: c#, sockets, filestream

i was looking for a way to send file through Socket on C# but i was not lucky to find sample code or ...
as you know in Socket we should send an array of byte and array length is MaxInt and a file is larger than MaxInt.
is there a way to send a FileStream through windows Socket on C# ?

Comment: Read some bytes, send some bytes, and you'll do fine.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24017/File-Transfer-using-Socket-Application-in-C-NET-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file in chunks (for example 64KB at once). Send each chuck individually. That allows you to stream arbitrarily large files.

Starting with .NET 4.0 you can use `Stream.CopyTo(Stream)` to make this a one-liner.

Comment: Or if on .Net 4.0 could probably just use the [`FileStream.CopyTo(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.copyto.aspx) overload and let the framework handle the chunking.

Comment: ...you can't copy stream to stream until you construct a NetworkStream around the socket: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd8fz0y3.aspx